# MySQL - проблема переноса запроса в Delphi. В чём может быть проблема?

Tags: mysql, delphi

Делал исходя из написанного в [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html), получилось так:

```
DELETE FROM table_name;
SET NAMES 'utf8';
SET CHARACTER SET utf8;

LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/backups/file_from_bd.csv' INTO TABLE table_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';
```

Сам запрос рабочий.
Но вот стоило его внедрить в Delphi, то всё, тут же стал выпадать в `Syntax Error from MySQL`

Скрин ошибки:
[image: Ошибка mySQL- еггог]

Код Delphi:

```
  ADOQuery1.Close;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;

  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('DELETE FROM table_name;');
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SET NAMES ''utf8'';');
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;');
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('LOAD DATA INFILE ''c:/backups/file_from_bd.csv'' INTO TABLE table_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY '';'' ENCLOSED BY ''"'' LINES TERMINATED BY ''\\n'';');

  ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  ADOQuery1.Close;
```

Если я правильно понимаю, то "ноги" данной ошибки произрастают из-за использования драйвера "mysql connector odbc 5.2.7", который используется для соединением с СУБД mySQL?
Или как решается данный вопрос?
И решается ли он, не прибегая к консольному методу загрузки данных в БД?

Comment: Такое впечатление, что не поддерживаются мультизапросы. Проверьте, будет ли работать, если каждый запрос выполнять отдельным `ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;`.

Comment: а если не query использовать а command?

Comment: @Akina - Точно! Попробовал на каждый ADOQuery1.ExecSQL и сработало!

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток.
В свое время были проблемы в использованием кирилицы при работе с MySql Embedded.
Сработал вот такой запрос.

```
ADOConnection.ExecSQL('SET NAMES cp1251;');
```

Может быть вам не нужно utf8 обрамлять апострофами?

Comment: Ой! Извиняюсь, заголовок вопроса остался от решённого, но сама суть в вопросе актуальна. Таблицы у меня в UTF-8

Comment: Замените в моем примере cp1251 на utf8 и попробуйте.

Comment: Что-то я ваш код не пойму? У `ADOConnection1` нет функции ExecSQL, по крайней мере в моей Delphi XE. Есть процедура `Execute`.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Это было для FireDac. Для Ado используйте Execute.